# iphone safari reader styles

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I'm currently optimizing my website for iphones and trying to understand the safari reader function.

I think it's a great feature for websites with long text, like mine, but I would like to style it just a bit.

Is there a way to style the text in the reader? All I would like to do is add a divider line to break the sections of text. I have tried adding hr tags to the html and adding border-bottoms to the div to see if i could, but both have failed.

Some of my html

```
<div class="storyReader">
  <div class="headerBlock">
     <p>Title</p>
     <p>Author</p>
     <p>Description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="contentBlock">
    <p>This is the really long content. This is the really long content. This is the really long content.</p>
    <p>This is the really long content. This is the really long content. This is the really long content.</p>
    <p>This is the really long content. This is the really long content. This is the really long content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `<hr>` where you want breaks, and hiding them in your CSS (so they only display in Reader mode, not on your normal site). I'm guessing on that, not sure if it would work.

Also, check out [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingWiththeReader/WorkingWiththeReader.html).

Comment: I've already tried placing hr tags, but they don't show up in the reader. In my original document that's what I'm using the separate the content. Thank you for that document. I'm working with the mobile safari though and not working with an extension...